# Why i cannot see a file which copied from cmd to android sd card?

Tags: android

I am trying to copy a file from my pc to the Samsung Table S4 SD card via cmd(Windows 7).I use the xcopy command.Everything seems to be okay.A message "1 file copied " appears and when i try to overwrite the file to the folder located in SD, file exists.
However, i cannot see the file by entering the SD contents from MyComputer.
Also when i type dir in the cmd command , file does not appear.

IF i manually copy the file (by copy and paste from PC to SD card), then file appears in the folder located in SD CARD.

Why does it happen?

Comment: I highly doubt a DOS utility properly supports MTP. You should be using `adb push` if you want a commandline copy solution.

Comment: I will try it.Thank you very much!